# How does Python's "import" work internally?

Tags: python, import, module

When you import a module, then reimport it again, will it get reimported/overwritten, or skipped?
When you import module "a" and "b", but also have module "b" imported in module "a", what happens? Is it safe to do this? For example if that module "b" has a class instantiated in it, will you end up instantiating it twice?

Comment: The documentation seems quite clear on this.  What part of the documentation confused you?  Can you provide specific quotes or links to the part that confused you?  It's not clear what part of it is confusing.  For example, http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules seems clear.  Can you please explain what part of this confused you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`import` loads the matching `.py`, `.pyc` or `.pyo` file, creates a module object, and stores it with its fully qualified ("dotted") name in the `sys.modules` dictionary.  If a second `import` finds the module to import in this dictionary, it will return it without loading the file again.

To answer your questions:

> When you import a module, then reimport it again, will it get reimported/overwritten, or skipped?

It will get skipped.  To explicitely re-import a module, use the `reload()` built-in function.

> When you import module "a" and "b", but also have module "b" imported in module "a", what happens?

`import a` will load `a` from `a.py[c]`, `import b` will return the module `sys.modules['b']` already loaded by `a`.

> Is it safe to do this?

Yes, absolutely.

> For example if that module "b" has a class instantiated in it, will you end up instantiating it twice?

Nope.

Answer (score 3):

The module will only be instantiated once. It is safe to import the same module in multiple other modules. If there is a class instance (object) that is created in the module itself, the very same object will be accessed from all modules that import it.

You can, if you like, have a look at all imported modules:

```
import sys
print sys.modules
```

`sys.modules` is dictionary which maps module names the module objects. The first thing the import statement does is looking in `sys.modules`, if it cannot find the module there, it will be instantiated, and added to `sys.modules` for future imports.

See this page for more details:
http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm (see "What Does Python Do to Import a Module?")

Comment: Nice answer! When imported for first time, an object of type `types.ModuleType` is initialized, when imported for second time only a reference to this object is created.

Comment: Caution: If you run a module (`__name__ == "__main__"`) and from another module you import this module, then this module is executed twice! (The second time the `__name__` is equal to the module-name)
Example:
main.py: `import xxx`
xxx.py: `import main`
run: `python main.py`